# OSX Swift add image into nstableview

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, nstableview

I have added a tableview and as well configured the cell with an identifier.
Everything works fine, the text of the cell gets displayed.
I have just one problem and don't know how to solve it.
How can I change the image of the tableview cell?

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let cellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("cell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

    cellView.textField!.stringValue = self.objects.objectAtIndex(row) as! String

    return cellView
}
```

How can I change the image which is also present inside the cell?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `NSTableCellView` with text and image has an outlet `imageView`

```
cellView.imageView!.image = NSImage(named:"MyImage")
```